# How to render data into table from a form component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I've very new to react and trying to learn react concepts while building an basic scheduling website.
Here I'm taking data from input field and storing in state but how to render this form data to table component?
Below I'm sharing Code and Files Strucutre
**Event Component aka main component**

```
import React from "react";
import {Container, Row, Table} from "react-bootstrap";
import EventModal from "./EventModalButton";

class EventList extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Container fluid="md">
                <Table striped bordered hover>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Python workshop</td>
                        <td>WorkShop</td>
                        <td>12:00PM</td>
                        <td>Saturday, 29/08/2020</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pandemic Situation</td>
                        <td>Webinar</td>
                        <td>02:00PM</td>
                        <td>Saturday, 29/08/2020</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </Table>

                <Container className="row"/>
                <Row className="justify-content-center">
                    // Open Modal Form to Add new Data
                    <EventModal />
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
export default EventList;
```

**EventModal.js which contains EventForm component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {Button, Modal} from "react-bootstrap";
import EventForm from "./EventForm";



function EventModal() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    return (
        <>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                Add New Event
            </Button>

            <Modal
                show={show}
                onHide={handleClose}
                backdrop="static"
                keyboard={false}
            >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>New Event</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <EventForm />
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
}
export default EventModal;
```

**Form to add new Date**

```
import React from "react";
import {Button, Container, Form} from "react-bootstrap";
import CustomDatePicker from "./CustomDatePicker";

const timeSlots = [

    {
        id: 1,
        value: '11:30AM'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        value: '12:00PM'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        value: '12:30PM'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        value: '01:00PM'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        value: '01:30PM'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        value: '02:00PM'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        value: '02:30PM'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        value: '03:00PM'
    },
];

const eventTypes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        value: 'Webinar',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        value: 'Workshop',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        value: 'Confernece',
    },
];

// for time slots
function Options({ options }) {
        return (
          options.map(option =>
              <option key={option.id} value={option.value}>
                  {option.value}
              </option>)
        );
}

// for event types
function Option({ options }) {
    return (
        options.map(option =>
            <option key={option.id} value={option.value}>
                {option.value}
            </option>)
    );
}


class EventForm extends React.Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            eventtype: null,
            time: null,
        }
    }

    handleTitleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            title: event.target.value
        })
    };

    handleTypeChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            eventtype: event.target.value
        })
    };

    handleTimeChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            time: event.target.value
        })
    };

    handleSubmit = () => {
      alert(`${this.state.title} ${this.state.eventtype}, ${this.state.time}`)
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Container fluid>

                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Form.Group controlId="Title">
                        <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control    placeholder="Event Title"
                                         name="title"
                                         value={this.state.title}
                                         onChange={this.handleTitleChange}/>
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId="EventType">
                        <Form.Label>Event Type</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="select"
                                      name="eventtype"
                                      value={this.state.eventtype}
                                      onChange={this.handleTypeChange}>
                            <Option options={eventTypes} />
                        </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId="Slots">
                        <Form.Label>Time Slots</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="select"
                                      name="time"
                                      value={this.state.time}
                                      onChange={this.handleTimeChange}>
                            <Options options={timeSlots} />
                        </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId="datepicker">
                        <Form.Label>Date</Form.Label>
                        <br/>
                        <CustomDatePicker/>
                    </Form.Group>
                        <Button
                            variant="primary"
                            type="submit">
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                </Form>

            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default EventForm;
```

As of now I only able to figure out to how to store user input data in state this is why I store dummy data in table for now. But how do I store this **EventForm.js** in a table called **EventList.js**?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new arrayState which is an array of objects.
2. When you receive input in your other states {title, eventType, time}, use the setArrayState of the newly created arrayState to add the inputs into your array state. (note: You will have to use the spread operator to make sure you don't wipe out the previous objects stored in your array state.)
3. Then pass that array state to the component in which you have created the table using props or the context API.
4. In the table component, use JavaScript's Array.map() function to map your data into the table and into the appropriate table fields. This will conditionally render your table as per the length of the array and the data stored in each of the array objects.

This video demonstrates how to render arrays in React -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ke1pkMV44iU

You can use the same principles in the video to render the array into your table.

Comment: Thank you! But there's an issue. On your 3rd step you said pass array state as props. but my form component is child component inside table component and I guess props can only be passed from parents to child but here child need to pass it's state to parent.

Comment: When you want to pass props from child to parent easiest solution is to use the context API to move the state to the top most component, your index.js, and consume the state in any of the components throughout your app. Here's a link that shows how to use context api -> https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/ You can also define the arrayState in the parent component, pass it as props into the child component, where it can update/set state and then use the updated state in the parent component. You can also use Redux or MobX state management libraries to do this.